# Volley, OKhttp Refresh Page Till Get Result GET METHOD Android

Tags: android, api, android-volley, okhttp

I'm using a hidden api(So, I can't change anything from server side) from an app and using it everything working fine but I need to refresh get method continuously to get updated response from url.
Problem is if I add wait of 1 second to refresh the method then it is working fine but If I'm not adding any wait then I got an "RateLimitExecption". So, if there any way I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your application can make limited requests a second for your user. If you can confirm that count it will be good, if no, you can find it by experiments. you can decrease 1 sec to ~100ms but in general, you can't have real-time data by using a GET request.

Comment: I also think so but in the main app from where I'm getting api in that app I can refresh it as many time continuously.